# How to get current usage per data center for object storage?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I can see the data in control.softlayer.com like below.
I tried to use 'getBandwidthBillingItems' for Hub API but this API returned only billing items without usage.

```
result:
   {
     dcPrivateIn: 0, 
     dcPrivateOut: 0, 
     dcPublicIn: 460534, 
     dcPublicOut: 21422144, 
     cdnFlash: 0, 
     cdnHttp: 0
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to use this method:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object/getBandwidthTotal

e.g using RestFul.

```
POST https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object/$metricTrackingObjectId/getBandwidthTotal

payload:
{
    "parameters": [
        "2016-05-03T23:00:00-0600",
        "2016-06-03T22:59:59-0600",
        "in",
        "public"
    ]

}
```

You need to get the "metricTrackingObjectId" for that you can use this RestFul

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage?objectMask=mask[metricTrackingObject]
```

The method above will list all the storages in your account and its "metricTrackingObjectId".

If you want more detailed data you can use this method:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object/getSummaryData

e.g.

```
POST https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object/$metricTrackingObjectId/getSummaryData

Payload:
{
    "parameters": [
        "2016-05-03T23:00:00-0600",
        "2016-06-03T22:59:59-0600", [{
            "keyName": "PUBLIC_BANDWIDTH_IN_LON02",
            "summaryType": "sum"
        }, {
            "keyName": "PUBLIC_BANDWIDTH_OUT_LON02",
            "summaryType": "sum"
        }, {
            "keyName": "PRIVATE_BANDWIDTH_IN_LON02",
            "summaryType": "sum"
        }, {
            "keyName": "PRIVATE_BANDWIDTH_OUT_LON02",
            "summaryType": "sum"
        }, {
            "keyName": "CDN_HTTP_BANDWIDTH",
            "summaryType": "sum"
        }],
        300
    ]

}
```

Just in case to get all the availabe "keyNames" you can use this method:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object/getMetricDataTypes

e.g

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object/$metricTrackingObjectId/getMetricDataTypes
```

Regards